# Debian - install new software by apt-get over SSH

Tags: ssh, installation, debian, putty, apt-get

I tried to install new software when I was connected to my Debian over SSH, for example `sudo apt-get install subversion`, and after calculating dependencies, required space, etc. APT asked, if I want to continue. When I answered Y (accept), terminal showed alert: `Aborted`. Why?

I want to install new software over ssh, I'm trying to install software from Putty (Windows).

**I tried:**

- log as root
- pass -t from putty

Nothing happened.

Comment: That's weird, I can confirm I have used `apt-get` remotely various times (though never through putty). Could you post the relevant section of your `/var/log/apt/term.log` please?

Comment: The actual error message you are getting could help too.

Comment: Instead of typing `Y`, try just press `Enter`. Accepting the changes should be the default, and this might fix some issue with erroneous input.

Comment: Oh, it's was something about configuring my Putty - I had to change encoding to UTF-8, till now I connected with ISO-8859, and I think server thought I was typing No all times...
But now it's something weird - I accept installation, see `0% working...`, and Debian ask me toput installation DVD to the drive, instead of downloading packets. Why?

Comment: @michail_w, because you've supposedly installed it from DVD media and so the only "package sources" which are available are those DVDs. You should edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add there something like `deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main` followed by `deb http://cdn.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main`, comment out the lines mentioning `cdrom`, then do `apt-get update` and the next `apt-get install ...` will reach for the nearest mirror holding the Debian archive.

Comment: @michail_w You can add an answer to your own question. In fact, that's better than just editing it.

Comment: I can't, it's my first post here, so my level is too low to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a problem like this,

1. make sure your putty connection encoding is proper (in my case UTF-8)
2. edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to comment/move cdrom repository